# Getting a “Your computer's running low on storage space” when 1/3 of my hard drive space is still free

Tags: hard-drive

I get this message:

> Your computer's running low on storage space. We can free some up by deleting your previous version of Windows.

But I've never had anything but Win10 on my one year old computer, what's up?  I checked and I have 1/3 of the space on my hard drive still free

Comment: It may be that something runs in the background that fills up your space, it reaches this threshold of 10 GB free, the message pops up, the installer removes its temporary files, and your harddrive is back to a level above the threshold. How big is your C partition? Also, check the content of C:\Windows\Temp and try to delete all files. It will say that some files are in use, skip these. I have cleaned 100GB of space at many pc's with diskspace issues in the past.

Comment: @walterglenn It could also be a virus running on your computer.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the Windows 10 periodic updates create a *huge* folder, [*C:\Windows.old*](https://www.howtogeek.com/223821/what-is-the-windows.old-folder-and-how-do-you-delete-it/), which has backup copies of previous Windows versions. The *safe* way to delete that folder is through Windows Disk Cleanup:

- Press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key and type **cleanup**.
- Click on *Disk Cleanup*.
- In the *Disk Cleanup: Drive Selection* dialog select the C: drive, where the Windows system folders are, and click *OK*.
- In the *Disk Cleanup for xxx (C:)* dialog, where *xxx* is the drive name, check all boxes and then click *Clean up system files*.
- Wait a few minutes while Windows calculates the amount of space to be cleared.

[image: Windows Disk Cleanup dialog]

If there are old versions of Windows 10 that can now be removed, *Previous Windows installation(s)* should indicate that a few GB can be freed on the drive.

- Click *OK* and take a break -- I've had cleanup take a few *hours* to complete.