# HP stream windows 10. office 360

Tags: office365, storage-spaces

I cant run the updates on my laptop because it says I have no room. I've got Office 365 free for the year and its seems to have taken all the space on the drive. Is there anything I can do to create more space?

[image]

Comment: How large is your Hard Drive? How much free space does it have? Have you run Disk Cleanup yet? In the picture I see you may have two versions of Office 365 and 2016. Can you uninstall one of them or are the actually the same?

Answer (score 0):

First, check which folders are taking up a lot of room. You can do this by right-clicking each folder and selecting *Properties*, or use an application  such as [Tree Size Free - Portable](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/treesize-free-portable), which will take up 7 MB on the drive. See if there are duplicate versions of your own files, e.g. automatic backups of Office documents, that you can manually delete.

Second, [use Windows Cleanup, which may free *quite a bit* of space](https://superuser.com/questions/1308205/getting-a-your-computers-running-low-on-storage-space-when-1-3-of-my-hard-dri/1308220#1308220) if you haven't used it after each update. Specifically, it removes old versions of Windows, which may be a few GB. Note that this may take hours, so let it run after you're done using the PC for the day.

Finally, [MS Office 365 itself takes up about 3 GB of drive space](https://btbusiness.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/18509/~/what-are-the-minimum-system-requirements-for-office-365%3F/c/5088/). You might try another office application suite such as free [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), which uses about 600 MB installed, one-fifth the space of the MS product.